# Firebase Storage Console 403 Error

Tags: firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-console

After deploying the sample storage trigger found [here](https://github.com/firebase/functions-samples/blob/master/quickstarts/thumbnails/functions/index.js) I can no longer access my storage console. I just see the spinner and the console gives me a 403 error.

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 403,
        "message": "You do not have permission to list buckets in project [...].",
        "status": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
        "details": [
            {
                "@type": "type.googleapis.com/google.internal.firebase.v1.ErrorCode"
            }
        ]
    }
}
```

This error produces a url in the console as well that when clicked leads to a response with a 401 error:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 401,
        "message": "Request is missing required authentication credential. Expected OAuth 2 access token, login cookie or other valid authentication credential. See https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/devconsole-project.",
        "status": "UNAUTHENTICATED"
      }
}
```

Perhaps it should be noted that the function logs indicate that the trigger is executing properly. I'm able to access all other areas of the console; e.g., database, functions, etc. This issue occurs on my mobiles device as well, which seems to rule out any browser related issues. Finally, the storage console works fine in other projects.

Comment: Is the entire Storage console broken? Or just some of the files? If the entire console is broken, I'd [reach out to Firebase support](https://firebase.google.com/support/contact/troubleshooting/) for personalized help in troubleshooting.

Comment: Yeah, nothing from the bucket loads at all--not even the rules. I've submitted a help ticket already. Was just hoping maybe someone here might know why this might be.

Comment: The problem is being tracked here: https://status.firebase.google.com/incident/Console/17010

Comment: Ha. So you're telling me it has nothing to do with my storage trigger?

Comment: You should not normally be able to cause this with your function, that's why it's being investigated.

Comment: As you can see in the link, the issue has been solved. It seems it was caused by an incompatible configuration change that was rolled back. Thanks for raising it! I'm voting to close this question, since it's ephemeral.